# How can I know and add an action to a dynamic number? javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a group of buttons (from 1 to 5). One button is the "winning number" and other one is "loser button"

I want to get an alert with a winning number and a loser number generated "random"

I'm receiving the random numbers, but not receiving the alert if some button is clicked ( TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null)

This is my code:

```
document.getElementById('newSorteo').onclick = function() {
    if (objPartida.iniciada) {
        open("panels / newSorteo.html", 'New draw', 'scrollbars = yes, width = 700, height = 1000, toolbar = yes');
    } else {
        msg('error', 'You must start a game to access');
        location.assign('index.html');
    }

    const numbers = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    let winnerNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    let loserNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1);
    console.log("The winning number is the" + winningNumber);
    console.log("The loser number is the" + loserNumber);

    for (let elemento of numbers) {
        element.onclick = function() {
            if (element[i] == winnerNumber) {
                alert("Winning number");
            }
            if (element[i] == loserNumber) {
                alert("loserNumber");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sorteo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
</head>

<body class="panel sorteo">

    <h1>¡Bienvenido!</h1>

    <p>Realiza un sorteo cada hora y podrás ganar 10.000$... ¡o un terrible terremoto!</p>

    <h2>¿A qué número apuestas?</h2>

    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>

    <div id="alerta"></div>

    <script src="../js/comun.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/nuevoSorteo.js"></script>


</body>
```

Comment: Do you have an element with the id 'newSorteo' ?

Comment: share the html as well, with this much only your issue can not be replicated

Comment: I've added html

Comment: @JuanJoséMuñoz Where is `newSorteo` defined?

Comment: `document.getElementById` looks for the `id` attribute. Meaning the only one that will work for you in this example is `document.getElementById("alerta")`.